# Detect changes in component input when it is a object

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a component which receives an input which is an object. `onchanges` does not detect changes on an object. So I need to use DoCheck to watch for changes on input object. So, in this case, I cannot use `oninit` method because even first-time `doCheck` method is hit. The problem is I cannot know is it the first time the data is initialized or its just data change. I need to do just some modification on data changes. Is there a better way to detect changes on input when it's an object so that I can know when it's the first set of data or just change of data.

Comment: Add an observable to the object that emits an event when a property is changes. You can do this by making properties getters/setters and emit an event in setters.

Comment: `ngOnInit` is called only once so you will know this the data initializations. Then inside `ngDoCheck` you can check for changes

Comment: Yes. First time both get called ngoninit and ngdocheck also.