# How can I detect changes in an Object and an Array when used as Input properties in a child component?

Tags: angular

I checked following two questions, but there aren't any useful answers:

1. [Detect change in object of input array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58734712/detect-change-in-object-of-input-array)
2. [Detect changes in component input when it is a object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45181269/detect-changes-in-component-input-when-it-is-a-object)

I have a scenario where I need to pass a different type of data to a child component using `@Input()`. By different type of data, I meant I've a string, a number, a Boolean, an object and an array.

**Parent HTML:**

```
<app-child
  [stringData]="stringData"
  [numberData]="numberData"
  [booleanData]="booleanData"
  [objectData]="objectData"
  [arrayData]="arrayData"
></app-child>

<button (click)="changeData()">Change data</button>
```

When I click on the button, the `changeData()` method is called. Here I'm modifying the data as follows:

**Parent TypeScript code:**

```
stringData: string = 'testing something';
numberData: number = 0;
booleanData: boolean = false;
objectData: any = {
  student: { name: 'tanzeel', batch: 2016 },
};
arrayData: any[] = ['banana'];

constructor() {}

changeData() {
  this.stringData = 'rolex watch';
  this.numberData = 100;
  this.booleanData = true;
  this.objectData.student.name = 'tajknzeel';
  this.arrayData.push('apple');
}
```

I'm receiving this data in the Child component as @Input properties.

**Child TypeScript code:**

```
@Input() stringData: any;
@Input() numberData: any;
@Input() booleanData: any;
@Input() objectData: any;
@Input() arrayData: any;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes);
}
```

The problem is that `objectData` and `arrayData` changes are going undetected.

**Console output:**

```
{
    "stringData": {
        "previousValue": "testing something",
        "currentValue": "rolex watch",
        "firstChange": false
    },
    "numberData": {
        "previousValue": 0,
        "currentValue": 100,
        "firstChange": false
    },
    "booleanData": {
        "previousValue": false,
        "currentValue": true,
        "firstChange": false
    }
}
```

What is the mistake in my code?

Comment: Mutating an object or array doesn't kick off the change detection mechanism. You have to reassign the values.

Answer (score 1):

The change detector only recognizes changes to the object reference, not its value.

For strings, numbers, and Booleans, changing the simple value actually does change the instance that the variable refers to.

For objects and arrays, you must change the instance of the object or array to trigger change detection. Changing an object property or the contents of the array does not trigger a change detection.

So, to make this work, change

```
this.objectData.student.name = 'tajknzeel';
this.arrayData.push('apple');
```

to

```
this.objectData = Object.assign(
   {},
   this.objectData,
   {
       student: Object.assign(
         {}, this.objectData, {name: 'tajknzeel'}
       )
   }
);
this.arrayData = [...this.arrayData, 'apple'];
```

Comment: I also noticed that I can trigger change for Object by doing this:
```
    this.objectData = {
      student: { name: 'tajknzeel', batch: 2018766 },
    };
```